# Sales Orders Add Invoice popup window Through Acumatica API

Tags: web, acumatica

Can someone share an example showing how to insert an Invoice using the action "Add Invoice" through the API.

I'm really out of clues, this code is what I have tried out already, but unsuccessfully (orginally posted by Serg Rogovtsev modified to fit AddInvoice popup parameters):

```
SO301000result = context.SO301000Submit(
    new Command[] 
    {                                                         
        new Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType },
        new Value { Value = ordNum, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr },

        //popup window                                           
        new Value { Value = "OK", LinkedCommand = SO301000.AddInvoiceDetails.DialogAnswer, Commit = true },
        new Value { Value = "Invoice", LinkedCommand = SO301000.AddInvoiceDetailsDocType.DocType },
        new Value { Value = "C0000155", LinkedCommand = SO301000.AddInvoiceDetailsDocType.RefNbr, Commit = true  },

       //HERE Error: One or more rows failed to validate

        new Key { Value = "='CPU00004'", FieldName = SO301000.AddInvoiceDetails.InventoryID_, ObjectName = SO301000.AddInvoiceDetails.InventoryID.ObjectName },
        new Value { Value = "True", LinkedCommand = SO301000.AddInvoiceDetails.Selected, Commit = true },

        SO301000.Actions.AddInvoice
        SO301000.Actions.Save
    }
);
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271116/screen-based-api-creation-of-po-receipt-from-poline-issue

Comment: Thank you Hybridzz. I saw the code in you link. This "AddInvoice" popup has no LineNbr Column, so I'd tried every field as Key value and always return error "One or mor rows failed to validate". I tried to send an "RowNumber" with values "1" or "CPU00004", but no sucess. Any ideas on how to select the row with out an LineNbr Column?

Comment: so you tried clearing the LinkedCommand and followed the same pattern of that answer?
can you paste the stack trace returned?

Comment: Thank you for following this issue: version 6 in this side; Clearing the LinkedCommand, same pattern; also tried similar examples from I200-Screen-Based-Web-Services-6.0_Jan.pdf This is the trace:

Comment: PX.Data.PXRowPersistingException: SO Error: One or more rows failed to validate. Please correct and try again.
   at PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry.SOLine_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
   at PX.Data.PXRowPersisting.Invoke(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()

Comment: at PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry.Persist()
   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<Handler>d__2.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2)
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()

Comment: at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.Submit(String screenId, IReadOnlyList`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, PXGraph& graph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Boolean mobile, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
   at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, Boolean mobile, PXGraph& forceGraph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)

Comment: at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode)
   at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: you can actually edit question and put this information there. by the way, where are you setting the customer information?

Comment: To simplify, I'm working in an pre-existing SO; tested updating the Note or Description, after that tried the AddInvoice button.